# Vim Dumb Indenting?

Tags: vim, indentation

Is there a way to just have Vim copy the indent from the line above, whether it be spaces or tabs, oblivious of the file types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what I've wanted isn't actually possible as Vim automatically removes whitespaces, and uses configuration settings for its indention.

I've avoided this put slapping these in to my vimrc:

```
:inoremap <CR> x<BS><CR>x<BS>
:inoremap <up> x<BS><up>
:inoremap <down> x<BS><down>
:nnoremap o ox<BS>
:nnoremap O Ox<BS>
```

It simply puts a character in place and then removes it before I exit the editing mode, so Vim doesn't remove the empty line. If this is the case then it may be simply Vim checking if any editing was done to the line, auto indenting not counted. Maybe someday I'll check out the source and poke around.

I also wanted to use the previous line's indent (so I'd get different indents for different files and not have to tamper with settings each time), but I've managed to compromise and use the lovely [Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171).

Answer (score 7):

`:set ai`

See `:help autoindent`

Comment: +1 I can't tell you how long I've been (vaguely) looking for this.

Comment: I've been through this whole ordeal before, autoindent doesn't copy from the line above, it uses settings.

Comment: @Jookia, it shouldn't. Make sure you have `set autoindent nocindent nosmartindent` the other two options interfere and these settings are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ah, but even after that it still converts 3 spaces to a tab and a space.

Comment: Try `]p` or `]P` for your paste operation.  That should take the indent from the line you're on.  I don't know how it works with tabs though, that may be `expandtabs` or a related setting.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are going to paste something and adjust the indent.

Try `]p`

Answer (score 0):

If you are at the beginning of the line and want to copy all the indenting characters above the line that you are currenly on now you can use Ctrl+y. It copies the character from the line above one at a time. Ctrl+e does the same thing but it copies from the line below.